Grounded Compressor - Freon
We are being told the reason for losing all refrigerant in an R12 system is a grounded compressor.  Is this possible?  We were also told there was a leak somewhere but then later told it was the grounded compressor.  A bit concerned we are being lied to.

Do the answers at Does a compressor with a short to ground really require a complete system replacement? help? (Including "get a second opinion.")

Might be a misunderstanding of words.  If talking about electrical grounding, then it does not make sense.  It is just a ground wire attached to the housing of the compressor and does not touch the insides or the freon/lines.  If the compressor is loose and causing rubbing/grinding of the lines.

By "grounded" do they mean that the suspension springs broke? Certainly makes no sense as stated, which implies electrical ground. Might be grounds to change repair service.

grounded or gridded

Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question and not just list words. We're humans, not a search engine.

I don't think R-12 has been used in residential HVAC in at least 30 years (and probably over 50), so if your system is using R-12, it is long past time to replace it in its entirety.  Or are you talking about an automotive A/C system, which is a different substack?

The reason to lose all the R12 is age of the equipment.  It's not indestructible and doesn't last forever.

Freon of any type is thoroughly sealed in any refrigeration system.  The grounding of a compressor, electrically or with the malfunction of springs will not allow the freon to escape.
For freon to leave the system there must be a leak.
You may have misunderstood what you were told.  An older system may not have the safeguards that newer systems have, as a result when the freon leaks out the system also loses the ability to cycle oil through the compressor. The result is a damaged compressor. This could be poorly explained to you as having a grounded or ground compressor.  The idea being the compressor damaged itself from lack of oil.
